# How do it clear all posted tasks which already queued in a strand?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

How do it clear all posted tasks which already queued in a `io_service::strand`? I see no similar method from boost document.

Comment: It is impossible. Consider redesigning the modules that require such a functionality.

Comment: Completely agreed. Just out of curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have yet to find a need for it, as it can be resolved correctly with properly designing the asynchronous call chains.  Generally, the Boost.Asio API is carefully designed in such a way that it prevents complex applications from becoming complicated in the asynchronous flow.

If you have examined the call chains, and are absolutely certain that the effort to redesign them is a greater current and future risk than introducing the complication of clearing a strand, then there is a way to accomplish it.  However, it does have the major side effect of deleting all uninvoked handlers within the `strand`, and its associated `io_service`.

When a `strand` is destroyed, its [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand/_strand.html) schedules uninvoked handlers for deferred invocation on the `io_service` maintaining the guarantee of non-concurrency.  The `io_service` [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) states that uninvoked handler objects that were scheduled for deferred invocation are destroyed.  Thus, by controlling the lifetime of a `strand` and `io_service`, one can clear the handlers in a strand.

Here is an overly simplified example with a helper class `clearable_strand`.

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>

class clearable_strand
{
public:
  clearable_strand(boost::asio::io_service& main_io_service)
    : main_io_service_(main_io_service)
  {
    clear();
  }

public:
  template <typename Handler>
  void post(const Handler& handler)
  {
    // Post handler into the local strand.
    local_strand_->post(handler);

    // Local service now has work, so post its run handler to the
    // main service.
    main_io_service_.post(boost::bind(
      &boost::asio::io_service::run_one, boost::ref(local_io_service_)));
  }

  void clear()
  {
    // Destroy previous (if any).
    local_strand_     = boost::none;
    local_io_service_ = boost::none;
    // Reconstruct.
    local_io_service_ = boost::in_place();
    local_strand_     = boost::in_place(boost::ref(local_io_service_.get()));
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service&                 main_io_service_;
  boost::optional<boost::asio::io_service> local_io_service_;
  boost::optional<boost::asio::strand>     local_strand_;
};
```

To minimize the effect so that only the `strand`'s handlers are destroyed, the class uses an internal `io_service` rather than attaching the `strand` to main `io_service`.  When work is posted to the `strand`, a handler is then posted to the main `io_service` that will daisy chain and service the local `io_service`.

And its usage:

```
void print(unsigned int x)
{
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  io_service.post(boost::bind(&print, 1));

  clearable_strand strand(io_service);
  strand.post(boost::bind(&print, 2));
  strand.post(boost::bind(&print, 3));
  strand.clear(); // Handler 2 and 3 deleted.

  strand.post(boost::bind(&print, 4));
  io_service.run();
}
```

Running the program will output `1` and `4`.  I would like to stress that it is an overly simplified example, and providing thread-safety in a non-complicated manner to match that of `boost::asio::strand` can be a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible, you will need to restructure your design depending on your goals. One possibility is to leverage the [prioritized handler example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp) if you desire certain high priority handlers to run before lower priority ones.

Comment: Your prioritized handler example is very interesting, and it can be very helpful for my future projects. I will bookmark this. Thank you.