# Clear boost::asio::io_service after stop()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using (single threaded) a `boost::asio:io_service` to handle a lot of tcp connections. For each connection I use a deadline_timer to catch timeouts. If any of the connections times out, I can use none of the results of the other connections. Therefore I want to completely restart my io_service. I thought that calling `io_service.stop()` would allow "finished" handlers in the queue to be called and would call handlers in the queue with an error.

However it looks like the handlers remain in the queue and therefore calling `io_service.reset()` and later `io_service.run()` brings the old handlers back up.
Can anyone confirm that the handlers indeed remain in the queue even after `io_service.stop()` is called. And if so, what are the possibilities to completly reset the io_service, e.g. remove all queued handlers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`io_service::stop()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html)  and [`io_service::reset()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/reset.html)  only control the state of the `io_service`'s event loop; neither affect the lifespan of handlers scheduled for deferred invocation (ready-to-run) or user-defined handler objects.

The [destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) for `io_service` will cause all outstanding handlers to be destroyed:

- Each service object associated with the `io_service` will have its `shutdown_service()` member function invoked.  Per the [Service](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Service.html) type requirement, the `shutdown_service()` member function will destroy all copies of user-defined handler objects that are held by the service.
- Uninvoked handler objects scheduled for deferred invocation are destroyed for the `io_service` and any of its strands.

Consider either:

- Controlling the lifespan of the `io_service` object.  One approach can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229613/1053968) answer.
- Running the `io_service` to completion.  This often requires setting state, cancelling outstanding operations, and preventing completion handlers from posting additional work into the `io_service`.  Boost.Asio provides an official [timeout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.timeouts) example, and a timeout approach with running to the `io_service` to completion is also shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858719).