# boost beast memory usage for bulk requests

Tags: c++, boost, openssl, boost-asio, boost-beast

I run this 
[boost-beast-client-async-ssl](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/http/client/async-ssl/http_client_async_ssl.cpp) example and it's OK. But, if I create 10000  sessions at same time, my program memory usage grows up to 400 MB and never down.  I'd test  without ssl (simple http), and there wasn't grows up memory.

Q: What's wrong with openssl ?

There is my *main* function.

```
    //up boost-beast-client-async-ssl session code.   
    struct io_context_runner
    {
        boost::asio::io_context * ioc;
        void operator()()const
        {
            try{
                boost::asio::io_context::work w(*ioc);
                ioc->run();
            }catch(std::exception& e){
                fprintf(stderr, "e: %s\n", e.what());
            }
        }
    };

int main(int argc, char* argv[] ){

    try
    {
        int total_run = 1;
        if (argc > 1) total_run = atoi(argv[1]);

        const char* const host = "104.236.162.70" ;// IP of  isocpp.org
        const char* const port =  "443";  // 
        const char* const target= "/" ; //

        std::string const body = ""; //
        int version =  11;

        // The io_context is required for all I/O
        boost::asio::io_context ioc;

        // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
        ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_client};

        // This holds the root certificate used for verification
        load_root_certificates(ctx);

        typedef std::shared_ptr< async_http_ssl::session > pointer;

        for(int i = 0; i < total_run; ++i){
            pointer s = std::make_shared< async_http_ssl::session >(ioc  , ctx   ) ;
            usleep( 1000000 / total_run ) ;
            s->run( host, port, target, version ) ;
        }
        // Launch the asynchronous operation
        //std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx)->run(host, port, target, version);

        // Run the I/O service. The call will return when
        // the get operation is complete.
        std::thread t{ io_context_runner{ &ioc } } ;

        t.join();

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
    catch(std::exception const& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

       return EXIT_SUCCESS ;
}
```

Edit:   ubuntu 14.04 , boost 1.66, g++ 4.9.4. OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014.

EDIT2:  According  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913157/boostasio-and-boostbind-functor-memory-is-never-released/37275288#37275288) question [malloc_trim](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html) frees ( return back to OS ) a lot of unused memory. Will be best, if boost asio itself supported malloc_trim for ssl connection  on unix systems !!.

Comment: Side note: [Should the exceptions thrown by `io_service::run` be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500924/85371). You should probably change `io_context_runner` to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems with the way you adapted that example:

1. the worker thread locks the io_service with the `work` instance so it will never complete
2. you `usleep` some time before spawning the async tasks, but you **never run any of the tasks** in the first place until the loop has completed... This means that all the delays are done before starting **any** work.

Here's my suggestion:

- run the service before starting the async tasks
- have 1 `work` instance lock the service in case the service would become idle before posting the next http request
- don't lock `work` inside the worker thread

### **<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>**

```
#include "example/common/root_certificates.hpp"

#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;    // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
namespace ssl = boost::asio::ssl;    // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
namespace http = boost::beast::http; // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Report a failure
void
fail(boost::system::error_code ec, char const* what)
{
    std::cerr << what << ": " << ec.message() << "\n";
}

// Performs an HTTP GET and prints the response
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    tcp::resolver resolver_;
    ssl::stream<tcp::socket> stream_;
    boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::request<http::empty_body> req_;
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;

public:
    // Resolver and stream require an io_context
    explicit
    session(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx)
        : resolver_(ioc)
        , stream_(ioc, ctx)
    {
    }

    // Start the asynchronous operation
    void
    run(
        char const* host,
        char const* port,
        char const* target,
        int version)
    {
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(stream_.native_handle(), host))
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category()};
            std::cerr << ec.message() << "\n";
            return;
        }

        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        req_.version(version);
        req_.method(http::verb::get);
        req_.target(target);
        req_.set(http::field::host, host);
        req_.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);

        // Look up the domain name
        resolver_.async_resolve(
            host,
            port,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_resolve,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_resolve(
        boost::system::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "resolve");

        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        boost::asio::async_connect(
            stream_.next_layer(),
            results.begin(),
            results.end(),
            std::bind(
                &session::on_connect,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_connect(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "connect");

        // Perform the SSL handshake
        stream_.async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_handshake,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_handshake(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "handshake");

        // Send the HTTP request to the remote host
        http::async_write(stream_, req_,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_write,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_write(
        boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "write");

        // Receive the HTTP response
        http::async_read(stream_, buffer_, res_,
            std::bind(
                &session::on_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1,
                std::placeholders::_2));
    }

    void
    on_read(
        boost::system::error_code ec,
        std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "read");

        // Write the message to standard out
        //std::cout << res_ << std::endl;

        // Gracefully close the stream
        stream_.async_shutdown(
            std::bind(
                &session::on_shutdown,
                shared_from_this(),
                std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    void
    on_shutdown(boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        if(ec == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            // Rationale:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587403/boost-asio-ssl-async-shutdown-always-finishes-with-an-error
            ec.assign(0, ec.category());
        }
        if(ec)
            return fail(ec, "shutdown");

        // If we get here then the connection is closed gracefully
    }
};

//up boost-beast-client-async-ssl session code.   
struct io_context_runner
{
    boost::asio::io_context& ioc;
    void operator()()const
    {
        try{
            ioc.run();
        }catch(std::exception& e){
            fprintf(stderr, "e: %s\n", e.what());
        }
    }
};

namespace async_http_ssl {
    using ::session;
}

#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // The io_context is required for all I/O
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    std::thread t;

    try {
        // Run the I/O service. The call will return when all work is complete
        boost::asio::io_context::work w(ioc);
        t = std::thread { io_context_runner{ioc} };

        int total_run = 1;
        if (argc > 1)
            total_run = atoi(argv[1]);

#if 0
        auto host = "104.236.162.70";                   // IP of  isocpp.org
        auto port = "443";                              //
        auto target = "/";                              //
#else
        auto host = "127.0.0.1";
        auto port = "443";
        auto target = "/BBB/http_client_async_ssl.cpp";
#endif

        std::string const body = ""; //
        int version = 11;

        // The SSL context is required, and holds certificates
        ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_client};

        // This holds the root certificate used for verification
        load_root_certificates(ctx);

        typedef std::shared_ptr<async_http_ssl::session> pointer;

        for (int i = 0; i < total_run; ++i) {
            pointer s = std::make_shared<async_http_ssl::session>(ioc, ctx);
            usleep(1000000 / total_run);
            s->run(host, port, target, version);
        }
    } catch (std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (t.joinable())
        t.join();

    // If we get here then the connections have been closed gracefully
}
```

On my system, memory profiling with 1 connection:

[image]

With 100 connections:

[image]

With 1000 connections:

[image]

### Analysis

What does it mean? It still seems that Beast is using progressively more memory when sending more requests, right?

Well, no. The problem is that you're starting requests faster than they can be completed. So, the memory load increases mainly because many `session` instances are extant at a given time. Once completed, they will free the resources automatically (due to the use of `shared_ptr<session>`).

### Making Requests Sequential

To drive the point home, here's a modified version that accepts a `on_completion_` handler with the session:

```
std::function<void()> on_complete_;

// Resolver and stream require an io_context
template <typename Handler>
explicit
session(boost::asio::io_context& ioc, ssl::context& ctx, Handler&& handler)
    : resolver_(ioc)
    , stream_(ioc, ctx)
    , on_complete_(std::forward<Handler>(handler))
{
}

~session() {
    if (on_complete_) on_complete_();
}
```

Now you can rewrite the main program logic as an async operation *chain*:

```
struct Tester {
    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    boost::optional<boost::asio::io_context::work> work{ioc};
    std::thread t { io_context_runner{ioc} };

    ssl::context ctx{ssl::context::sslv23_client};

    Tester() {
        load_root_certificates(ctx);
    }

    void run(int remaining = 1) {
        if (remaining <= 0)
            return;

        auto s = std::make_shared<session>(ioc, ctx, [=] { run(remaining - 1); });
        s->run("127.0.0.1", "443", "/BBB/http_client_async_ssl.cpp", 11);
    }

    ~Tester() {
        work.reset();
        if (t.joinable()) t.join();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tester tester;
    tester.run(argc>1? atoi(argv[1]):1);
}
```

With this program ([Full Code On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7a43d2aae2f86eb)), we get much more stable results:

- 1 request:

  [image]
- 100 requests:

  [image]
- 1000 requests:

  [image]

### Restoring Throughput

Well that's a bit too conservative, sending ***many*** requests might become really slow. How about *some* concurrency? Easy:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int const total      = argc>1? atoi(argv[1]) : 1;
    int const concurrent = argc>2? atoi(argv[2]) : 1;

    {
        std::vector<Tester> chains(concurrent);

        for (auto& chain : chains)
            chain.run(total / concurrent);
    }

    std::cout << "All done\n";
}
```

That's all! Now, we can have `concurrent` separate chains of executions servicing ~total requests. See the difference in run time:

```
$ time ./sotest 1000
All done

real    0m53.295s
user    0m13.124s
sys 0m0.232s
$ time ./sotest 1000 10
All done

real    0m8.808s
user    0m8.884s
sys 0m1.096s
```

With the memory usage continuing to look healthy:

[image]

Comment: Added three "chapters" explaining the profiling results and changing to limit concurrent sessions (and getting rid of the `usleeps`). Now doing 10,000 requests in 20 concurrent chains runs without errors and still with steady memory usage on my system: https://i.imgur.com/Vh9pFEz.png

Comment: 1) I don't understand, why << don't lock work inside the worker thread >>  ??


2) In real project,  io_context should never end, because it wait  requests from another  part of  system(clients). So, I can't implement As You Suggested.


3) Sorry, but It's not answer my question,  WHAT IS WRONG WITH OPENSSL??  i.e. WHY IT SO MANY MEMORY "EATS" , AND NEVER FREES ?

Comment: Wow. Dont shout. Nothing is wrong with OpenSsl. My tests make that very clear. (Reread the "Analysis" and "Making it sequential" sections). You can move the work lock to some other place. Just don't reset it unless you want a clean shutdown. Of course of you don't care about clean shutdown, you can keep it in the worker thread, but that males it hard to check for memory leaks. (Ironically libcrypto.so does leak a fixed amount of bytes).

Comment: @sehe well that's a pretty amazing answer! Since we're on the subject... I never could get the "http-crawl" example working fully, it seems to hang at the end. It is similar to what is being done here, it tries to concurrently visit 10,000 of the most popular Alexa-ranked websites and perform a GET. This is mainly a stress/performance test and something that could be useful to profile. Perhaps you could figure out why it hangs on the last few requests? Here it is: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/tree/develop/example/http/client/crawl

Comment: @VinnieFalco it would help if there was a clear issue on the actual problems with it. It would also be a good place for related discussion