# What io_service::stop actually do

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I wonder what `io_service::stop` actually do by [saying](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/stop.html)

> All invocations of its run() or run_one() member functions should
>   return as soon as possible

Does it interrupt any currently exeucuting handlers (that were called via `run` or `run_one`)? If so, how is it achieved (interruption points maybe)?

Does it clear any queued handlers posted via the `post` method?

Comment: It appears to depend on your platform. You can always look at the actual source by visiting the [github page](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/42e7869f411a75512fb6994c634eb086fb9eb5cc/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_io_service.ipp)

Comment: See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553886/clear-boostasioio-service-after-stop).